# Cannot add a tooltip to appear when the mouse hovers to a unity EditorGUILayout.Popup()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have a quite complex GUI in unity whit public override void OnInspectorGUI().
For all of my normal fieds I can add a tooltip with the header: Tooltip[("")] in the class itself.
However, I need a dynamic dropdown list that needs to be updated with the number of elements of a list.
I works great. Find the code of the custom editor script for the dropdown list:

```
        string[] options = new string[movParamsListSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < movParamsListSize; i++)
            options[i] = i.ToString();

        Rect r = EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        movStepToMoveTo.intValue = EditorGUILayout.Popup("movementStepToMoveTo",
        movStepToMoveTo.intValue, options, EditorStyles.popup);
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

Find also a screenShot:

[image]

My problem is that I tried with all the overloaded functions of the EditorGUILayout.Popup() function (image below from the metadata) and cannot figure out how to add a tooltip when the mouse hovers to this control.

[image]

Any help is much apprecciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the overload of [`EditorGUILayout.Popup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Popup.html) that takes  a [`GUIContent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIContent-ctor.html) instead:

```
EditorGUILayout.Popup(new GUIContent("movementStepToMoveTo", "YOUR TOOLTIP HERE"), movStepToMoveTo.intValue, options);
```

Btw the `EditorStyles.Popup` is redundant since this is the default for a `Popup` ;)

and also `HorizontalGroup` is quite redundant here. You have only one control anyway.

Comment: You rule man. You almost knew the text of my tooptip XD. Many thanks!!